# On the probability density function of a sum of two independent random variables derived from the cumulative distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am aware of the convolution approach, I was wondering if this approach is correct:

take $X$ and $Y$ independent random variables with continuous densities on $R$ respectively denoted $f,g$ and consider $P(X+Y < c)$

we have $$\begin{align*} P(X+Y < c) &= \int_R P(X+Y< c|X=x)f(x) \,dx \\ &= \int_R P(Y< c-x)f(x) \,dx \\ &= \int_R G(c-x)f(x) \,dx \end{align*}$$

where I have denoted with $G$ the cumulative distribution function of $Y$.

Now if we differentiate the result of the integral wrt $c$ we obtain the density of the sum of the random variables and this can be easily generalized to an arbitrary sum of random variables.

Is this approach correct? is it not used as much as the convolution approach for the difficulty that the integral $\int_R G(c-x)f(x) \,dx$ could pose?

Comment: Yes, it is correct, and you could get the same formula from integrating the convolution.  In many cases it is true that the cumulative distribution function is more complicated or less elementary than the density (case in point: normal distributions), possibly leading to a more difficult integration.